# Use prop value as a variable in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem about using prop value as a variable in VueJS. I have a component which I tranmit prop:

This is parent component:

```
<template>
  <div class="a">
    <UploadAvatarModal
      apiurl="upload_avatar"
      id="UploadAvatarModal"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

This is script of `UploadAvatarModal` component:

```
<template>
  <div class="a">
     ...
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: String,
    apiurl: String
  },
  methods: {
    def: function () {
      this.$refs.id.hide()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In this line: `this.$refs.id.hide()` How can I call methods according to `prop id`. Example: this.$refs.**UploadAvatarModal**.hide() or this.$refs.**UploadAvatarModal2**.hide() changed by props value??

Comment: You can send custom event from child component to parent component with child id and then in parent you can hide modal with v-if or v-show

Comment: This is not methods for hiding modal. Do you have any ways to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly want to do. Please explain it clearly

Comment: you want to pass an element id to hide it with jquery? if it is, then it is not the way you should do it in vuejs. Like @CaShiS said, you need to pass an event from child to parent to hide a child.

My recommendation is not to use jquery with vuejs and use vuejs as it is (unless there is a real necessity for jquery)

Comment: @DuyAnh there is no real necessity for using jquery while using vuejs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access props doing :

```
this.propName
```

To access id prop you need to do :

```
this.id
```

So the line you wrote `this.$refs.id.hide()` should be written :

```
this.$refs[this.id].hide()
```

But it will probably do nothing as .hide() is a jquery function. 
In plain javascript you would need to do :

```
this.$refs[this.id].style.display = 'none'
```

That said, it's  might not be a good idea to do so. 
Using vue, the best way to show/hide a component is probably to use `v-if` or `v-show`